# Eclipse export/print contents of debug variable

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse for embedded project development (C language). I debug my project and in Expressions window I have an array (1024 x 2 integer elements). I want to export contents of this array to clipboard/file so I can process the data from the array in another software. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My solution so far is to use the debug mode and to type in the debug console the command

```
print varName@number
```

whereas number gives you the number of elements to be display. In your case it should be

```
print array@1024
```

For me the debug console is the 5th ribbon on the console view at the bottom of the debug screen. This is advice from an eclipse newbie to another eclipse newbie, maybe someone has a better idea...

Comment: This seems to truncate to 200 items

Answer (score 0):

Found this [article](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2020/04/13/dumping-variables-and-arrays-with-gdb-in-eclipse/) which describes a way to output the array into a .srec file format using the debug command.

```
dump srec value c:\\file\\to\\path\\name.srec arrayIwantToExport
```

If array exceeds 64 KB, you can increase the max value as described [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Value-Sizes.html).